# How to get each substring in a file by Ant

Tags: ant

I have a file contains following lines of strings separated by "|",

```
C:\Temp\demo\AAA.dat   |    C:\test\input\AAA.dat
C:\Temp\build\BBB.bat  |    C:\test\java\BBB.bat
C:\Temp\test\CCC.xml   |    C:\Apps\ftp\CCC.xml
```

after I read each line, I hope to extract each string separated by "|",
ie, after i get 1st line,
I need to get both C:\Temp\demo\AAA.dat and C:\test\input\AAA.dat;
Pls help how to use ant to do it???

I use following code I can only get each line :

```
<loadfile property="filelist" srcfile="C:\Temp\file1.txt"/>
<target name="test" depends="chkInput" description="test">

    <for param = "line" list="${filelist}" delimiter="${line.separator}"> 
       <sequential> 
            <echo>@{line}</echo> 
       </sequential> 
    </for> 
</target>
```

Not each substring separated by "|", pls help how to get each substring separated by "|"?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the line, you can use `<propertyregex>` to separate the two pieces.

```
<for param = "line" list="${filelist}" delimiter="${line.separator}"> 
   <sequential> 
        <echo>@{line}</echo>
        <var name="first.part" unset="true"/>
        <var name="second.part" unset="true"/>
        <propertyregex
            property="first.part"
            input="@{line}"
            regex="^([^\s]*)"
            select="\1"/>
        <propertyregex
            property="second.part"
            input="@{line}"
            regex="\|\s*([^\s]*).*$"
            select="\1"/>
   </sequential> 
</for>
```

Note you have to use either the `<var/>` task to *unset* the property (or otherwise, you're not changing the property, or the new  task to declare that property is local to the `<sequential/>` entity.